# Laravel 5.0 git push failed in openshift

Tags: php, laravel-5, openshift

When i push my project in `openshift` it's show some error and after that home page show blank. Please tell me how to overcome this problem.
Show this *Error*:

```
remote: Migrating storage and log directories...
remote: Running 'php artisan migrate --force'...
remote: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/lib/openshift/5625fa370c1e66983300012f/app-root/runtime/repo/config/app.php on line 147
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure
remote: Activation status: failure
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:
remote: 5625fa370c1e66983300012f (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute action hook 'deploy' for 5625fa370c1e66983300012f application supportti    cketsystem
remote: #<IO:0x00000002268390>
remote: #<IO:0x00000002268318>
remote: )
remote: Deployment completed with status: failure
remote: postreceive failed
To ssh://5625fa370c1e66983300012f@supportticketsystem-zahidulislam.rhcloud.com/~    /git/supportticketsystem.git/
d2e663c..6122fb1  master -> master
```

[This error show when i push my project in openshift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE7oI.png)

*Config/app.php* file code:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe.
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'eaAJlaAlABGDmSOIOoBKZBuwZnGdjYMn'),

    'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Logging Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
    | the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
    | you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
    |
    | Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
    |
    */

    'log' => 'daily',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

        Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
        'Artisan'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
        'Auth'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
        'Blade'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
        'Bus'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus',
        'Cache'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
        'Config'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
        'Cookie'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
        'Crypt'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
        'DB'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
        'Eloquent'  => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
        'Event'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
        'File'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
        'Hash'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
        'Input'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
        'Inspiring' => 'Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring',
        'Lang'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
        'Log'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
        'Mail'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
        'Password'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
        'Queue'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
        'Redirect'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
        'Redis'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
        'Request'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
        'Response'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
        'Route'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
        'Schema'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
        'Session'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
        'Storage'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage',
        'URL'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
        'Validator' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
        'View'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',
        'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,

    ],

];
```

[Config/app.php file..... line 147's code pic is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAEVF.png)

Comment: You have a Syntax error in `config/app.php`. Please post the contents of that file :)

Comment: i put the hole code of config/app.php file check the post and here is a screenshot i dont found any error http://i.stack.imgur.com/aAEVF.png please told me where is error @Dencker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push itself is not failing, what is failing is the php parsing of your `config/app.php`, which has a syntax error.

The class name resolution using `::class` is only supported since [`PHP >= 5.5`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class). You need to import the `HtmlServiceProvider` as:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

Also, to run Laravel 5.0 you need to have [`PHP >= 5.4`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements), so make sure you're not using `5.3`

Comment: i put the hole code of config/app.php file check the post and here is a screenshot i dont found any error http://i.stack.imgur.com/aAEVF.png please told me where is error @João

Comment: Thank you so much @João finally problem solve :) Thanks a looooooot again :)